# Add standard error as shaded area instead of errorbars in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, errorbar

I have my `boxplot` and I added the mean with `stat_summary` as a line over the box plot. I want to add the *standard error*, but I don't want *errorbar*.

Basically, I want to add the *standard error* as *shaded area*, as you can do using `geom_ribbon`.

I used the `PlantGrowth` dataset to show you briefly what I've tried.

```r
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(group, weight))+ 
stat_boxplot( geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5)+ 
geom_boxplot(fill="yellow4",colour="black",outlier.shape=NA) + 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="black", geom="line", shape=18, size=1,aes(group=1))+ 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar")
```

I did it using `geom_errorbar` in `stat_summary`, and tried to substitute `geom_errorbar` with `geom_ribbon`, as I saw in some other examples around the web, but it doesn't work.

Something like this one, but with the error as shaded area instead of error bars (which make it a bit confusing to see)

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of what type of visual you want? I'm not quite picturing it

Comment: I replied with a picture and and explanation into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layering so many geoms becomes hard to read, but here's a simplified version with a few options. Aside from just paring things down a bit to see what I was editing, I added a tile as a summary geom; tile is similar to rect, except it assumes it will be centered at whatever its x value is, so you don't need to worry about the x-axis placement that `geom_rect` requires. You might experiment with fill colors and opacity—I made the boxplots white just to illustrate better.

```r
library(ggplot2) 

gg <- ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x = group, y = weight)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "white", outlier.shape = NA, width = 0.7) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 1), fun.y = mean, geom = "line")

gg +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "tile", width = 0.7,
               fill = "pink", alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

Based on your comments that you want a ribbon, you could instead use a ribbon with `group = 1` the same as for the line.

```r
gg +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 1), fun.data = mean_se, geom = "ribbon", 
               fill = "pink", alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

The ribbon doesn't make a lot of sense across a discrete variable, but here's an example with some dummy data for a continuous group, where this setup becomes more reasonable (though IMO still hard to read).

```r
pg2 <- PlantGrowth
set.seed(123)
pg2$cont_group <- floor(runif(nrow(pg2), 1, 6))

ggplot(pg2, aes(x = cont_group, y = weight, group = cont_group)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "white", outlier.shape = NA, width = 0.7) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 1), fun.y = mean, geom = "line") +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 1), fun.data = mean_se, geom = "ribbon", 
               fill = "pink", alpha = 0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Camille.
I thought it was easy to explain.
I added a line on the box plot, that represent the mean (usually the boxplot rapresent the median as an indicator of central tendency).
I want also represent the standard error, but with the shaded area and not with the error bars.
I want a line like this: https://images.app.goo.gl/Lb9AhtUeAnrmpdsy6

Comment: The particular is the I didn't calculate mean and se before and I don't have these data in my data frame.
To be faster (I thought) and less laborious with the code.
So I can't use geom_line and geom_ribbon and I tried to use the stat_summary function to calculate direclty these statistics to plot them.
The function calculate well these statistics, but add the error only as error bars and not as shaded area.
Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't how.

I hope I was clearer.

Comment: @AntonioManco a ribbon like that doesn't make a whole lot of sense since the x-axis is discrete, not continuous, so it might be misleading

Comment: I used the PlantGrowth dataset just to give a simple dateset to reproduce my plot, because my dataset is little bit bigger and complicated to share.
I have a continuous x axis, with the hours of the day.

Comment: Ooook. Now is like I want it for my plot with continuous x axis!
Thanks @camille!